# Placing The Section Header Above the Cell Contents of UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard, alignment

**You may want to go 'Edit 2' section directly (at below), there you can find the last and current situation.

I can't explain the problem just with the words properly, so I'll try to explain with pictures. Here is the situation I have:

[image]

As you can see in the picture, the allignment of the header titles doesn't match with the contents of the TableViewCell. I want section header to be at the top of the values. Like, "Alış" string to be at the beginning of the values. To be specific, I want something like that:

```
 Alış             Satış

 654.000          666.000

 313.757          321.921

 157.370          160.960

 ...              ...
```

And so on.

I was referring to [this link](http://www.accella.net/custom-header-and-footer-views-for-uitableviews/) to make section headers. Of course, it is a simple doc, so I moved myself using "auto layout" and "update frames" and "add the missing constraints" from the `Resolve Auto Layout Issues` segment that storyboard has. Well, clearly I failed. Here is the tableView that refers to this problem:

[image]

So here, the second cell is used for the header, as suggested in the link I gave.

I'm not familiar with using constraint, that is making the issue more complicated to me.

Any help / suggestion would be appreciated.

Waiting for your assistance.

**EDIT:**

Here is the code I have to write header.

[image]

**EDIT 2: Now, I'm really close and just need a little assistance**

I was trying 'til the morning on this, I know it is a bit much time. Anyway. So eventually I figured it out and tried in iPhone 4s to 6 plus, they give the correct result, with a minor mistake. The answer was simple: playing with the autolayout to understand with reference. I recommend Apple's doc and Ray's doc.

Back to last problem, as you can see in the first picture, my last row of tableVieWCell's alignment is right which I want it to be left. So the last situation is at below:

[image]

**I worht mentioning that I know that the alignment may not be what is my topic, but I didn't want to ask another question. If it is really unappropite, you can warn me, so I can ask in another topic.

Comment: Without knowing the constraints being used, accurately troubleshooting this is near impossible. I would suggest learning more about autolayout via the numerous resources online.

Comment: How you are giving the  string to header?

Comment: Well I didn't say I don't know, I'm just new. Need to start somewhere, though it can be here. I am adding right away @T_77

Comment: Please shows us the code where you are adding the header to the tableview?

Comment: Yeah of course, I was adding it. It is added now.

Answer (score 0):

Please make seperate xib file with class file .h & .m and it's superview is UIView for section header. And design the same view which you have design for table cell. You can use autolayout also in xib file. This will work :-)